# Logic App EDI send - unable to serialize the schema

Tags: xml, azure, azure-logic-apps, edifact

I have a logic app in charge of sending an EDIFACT message to a partner.
I have an agreement between my partner and my company both for receiving and sending messages.
I need to send ORDRSP message to this partner.

The agreement is configured as follow:
[image]

The send settings is configured as show below:
[image]

When I try to encode the message in the logic app thanks to the EDI Encode action, I received the following error :

> "errorMessage": "Message cannot be serialized since the schema 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/EDI/EDIFACT/2006#EFACT_D96A_ORDRSP_EAN005' could not be located. Schema reference could not be found in the agreement send settings."

The schema is deployed in the integration account, I double checked.

It sounds like the the EDI encode action is not able to locate my schema.

The only thing that is important to notice is that I added _EAN005 to the root node of the schema because I use the same schema in the receive part of the process and in order to be able to locate the schema (according to this post [How to handle EDIFACT documents having UNH2.5 segment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-edifact_inputfile_unh2.5).

Thanks.

Comment: Have you set the UNH2.5 value to EAN005 on Send Settings?

Comment: It is not possible to set the UNH2.5 value in the send settings as you can see in the screen shot in my message (second screenshot).

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this issue, I modified the Agreement, Send Settings part to add the EAN005 (but I need to do that in the JSON code itself).